# How to set Content-type in php on mac?

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, content-type

I've the problem. Here is my code of php:

```
include "connection.php";

$patternJPG = '/.pdf$/i';
$gfs = $db->getGridFS();
$collection=$db->Children;
$selected = array('_id'=> new MongoId($_GET['id']));
$cursor=$collection->find($selected);
foreach($cursor as $b){
        $id1 = $b["photoID"];

        $criteria = array("_id" => New MongoId ($id1));
        $nameOriginal = $gfs->findOne($criteria)->file['filename'];
        if(preg_match($patternJPG, $nameOriginal)){
        $row = $gfs->findOne($criteria)->getBytes();
        $mimeType = 'Content-type: application/pdf';
        header("Content-Length: " . strlen($row)); 
        header($mimeType); 
        ob_end_clean(); 
        flush();
        echo($row);
        }

        }
```

This code literally works on windows platform. When I try to run that code on mac, it doesn't work. I think that code should be worked on all platform instead. Becase all this time, I never have found the problem like this. I have the code that working on windows, that code also work on mac. Please someone help me for fixing this issue.

[image: windows]

[image: mac]

Comment: It is not clear what exactly not working. Is it when you open the URL from Safari, you cannot download the PDF file? How is it working on windows?

Comment: It is working on windows such as showing up the pdf and there is tools for download, print, etc. But, it doesn't work on mac because its just showing abstract alphabet like 64-bit encode maybe.

Comment: Is there a PDF plugin on the Mac?

Comment: I don't have pdf plugin. No require anything on windows. I think on mac is automatically working ? Or need pdf plugin if you want to show pdf on mac browser ? @JeroenHeier

Comment: Is it working on Safari? Do the headers get delivered to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

There is one post on [similar issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/A3XrBbHD80U)

> Well, Chrome is meant to be a basic browser that is customizable to your needs with extensions. Our Web App Store features a bunch of free, handy dandy extensions that will let you view PDFs right in your browser.

Please try to install a plugin to view the PDF files in chrome on MacOS

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/pdf%20viewer?hl=en

Also, one way to make sure you have your server side code correct is to save the output as a file with `.pdf` extension and try to open it to make sure it is a correct PDF.

If it is required to force Chrome to download the file instead of viewing it so the file can be viewed by the system PDF viewer.  You can use the header `Content-Disposition: attachment` as per this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1194701/how-to-force-google-chrome-to-only-download-pdf-but-not-open-them).

Comment: The report said Adobe Acrobat for Chrome is not yet available for Mac. :(

Comment: Update the link to show pdf extension. on the other hand, have you tried to save the file and view it with your pdf viewer on MacOS?

Comment: You can force download the file instead of viewing it, then you can view it with system viewer.

Comment: How can I try to save when the adobe is not working :( This browser is still showing an abstract alphabet. Is there way to fixing this issue ?